# ASP.NET linkbutton enabled=false does not work in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, webforms, linkbutton

I want to disable an ASP.NET `linkbutton`. What I want is a solution where browsers won't let me click on the linkbutton or at least where the associated action is not executed.

I do the following on the HTML markup using `WebForms`:

```
 <asp:LinkButton
       id="link1"
       text="Some button"
       runat="server"
       Enabled ="false"
 />
```

I trigger the link button action using jQuery events:

```
$('#link1').click(function (evt) {
    // Do something here
    return false;
});
```

- In IE8 it is disabled and does not allow click
- In Chrome it's not disabled but id does not allow click
- In Firefox 41.0.1 I can still click the link button and perform the action

The result is the same if I disable it in code behind:

```
this.link1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I update the question. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792194/why-are-linkbuttons-not-grayed-out-when-disabled-in-firefox

Comment: @devlincarnate The main problem is that I can click on the link. Css are not applyed either, for that link may help me.

Comment: You could use JQUERY to simply change the state from enabled to disabled onLoad event. Are you positive that it is disabled, or is the CSS just coming across as looking like its enabled...

Comment: @TGarrett Yes I'm sure i'ts disabled because I cannot click in the link.

Comment: In your button action function, you could check the button's disabled state before executing any further actions.

Comment: I would simply use js to do a check to see if it is disabled or not, if it is not and it should be, make it disabled. Have you tried making the linkbutton disabled on the page load in the backend?!

Comment: @TGarrett Thank you. Yes It's still disabled if I disabled it in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a Linkbutton disabled does not prevent it from being clicked. In my test a disabled linkbutton rendered like this:

```
<a class="aspNetDisabled">test</a>
```

jQuery will happily attach a click event to that anchor tag. You need to either prevent the event from triggering, or change the code so that it only performs your actions when the button is enabled.

Here's a possible work-around which will only execute your js if the button is enabled:

```
$('#link1').click(function (evt) {
    if('<%=link1.Enabled%>' === 'True') {
      // Do something here
    }
    return false;
});
```

Even if the client triggers the disabled button, the if statement will cause `Do something here` to not run.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether it's been missed in your simplification but it seems that your jQuery would not be executed due to a change in the button's client side ID. You will need to do either of the following:

**Set `ClientIDMode` to `static` on your control ...**

To ensure that the `id` remains as `link1` for use in your client side code.

```
<asp:LinkButton
    id="link1"
    text="Some button"
    runat="server"
    Enabled ="false"
    ClientIDMode="static"
    />
```

**or, obtaining the ID of the your control in your jQuery at runtime ...**

Although this will only work if your jQuery is within the same web form page, not external JS.

```
$('#<%= link1.ClientID %>').click(function (evt) {
    // Do something here
    return false;
});
```

**Whichever you choose ...**

If it correctly linked, you can then use jQuery's [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method to disable the post back from triggering.

```
$('#link1').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Do something here
});
```